# Can not access ppa:chris-lea/node.js

Tags: node.js

When I try to install node.js on ubuntu server 13.04 I'll receive the following error message:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.

Any help would be nice.
Sebastian

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved. IT fixed it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

It works fine on my 13.04

Comment: No, I'll always get: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? In many cases bad proxy configuration doesn't allow ppa to reach you. Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131982/i-cant-add-ppa-repositories

Comment: Thank you very much. IT enabled the gateway for missing internet connection. Ubuntu Server and Shiny Server is running...

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this issue with an Ubuntu instance from Amazon Web Service - EC2, Check that the instance security group has correct Outbound rule :

The one i missed :

```
HTTPS TCP  443 0.0.0.0/0
```

After adding the repository, delete the rule if not needed.